# Why I cannot convert this list as a string to be a real list in Common Lisp?

Tags: type-conversion, common-lisp

I have a local `.lisp` file with this content:

```lisp
 ((:DATE @2021-08-04T17:36:57.804411-03:00 :URL
   "https://www.facebook.com/r.php")
  (|:name| "jazoest" |:value| "2985" |:type| "hidden")
  (|:name| "lsd" |:value| "AVpp0Bi0ysk" |:type| "hidden")
    (|:id| "u_0_y_q3" |:name| "custom_gender" |:type| "text")
  (|:id| "referrer" |:name| "referrer" |:type| "hidden")
  (|:id| "asked_to_login" |:name| "asked_to_login" |:value| "0" |:type|
   "hidden")
  (|:id| "use_custom_gender" |:name| "use_custom_gender" |:type| "hidden")
  (|:id| "terms" |:name| "terms" |:value| "on" |:type| "hidden")
  (|:id| "ns" |:name| "ns" |:value| "0" |:type| "hidden")
  (|:id| "ri" |:name| "ri" |:value| "afc4dac1-259a-4006-a979-8ab182d93cce"
   |:type| "hidden")
  (|:id| "action_dialog_shown" |:name| "action_dialog_shown" |:type| "hidden")
  (|:id| "invid" |:name| "invid" |:type| "hidden")
    (|:id| "captcha_response" |:name| "captcha_response" |:type| "hidden"))
```

I can read it with:

```
(uiop:read-file-string "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/input-data.lisp")
```

Which returns:

```
" ((:DATE @2021-08-04T17:36:57.804411-03:00 :URL
   \"https://www.facebook.com/r.php\")
  (|:name| \"jazoest\" |:value| \"2985\" |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:name| \"lsd\" |:value| \"AVpp0Bi0ysk\" |:type| \"hidden\")
    (|:id| \"u_0_y_q3\" |:name| \"custom_gender\" |:type| \"text\")
  (|:id| \"referrer\" |:name| \"referrer\" |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"asked_to_login\" |:name| \"asked_to_login\" |:value| \"0\" |:type|
   \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"use_custom_gender\" |:name| \"use_custom_gender\" |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"terms\" |:name| \"terms\" |:value| \"on\" |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"ns\" |:name| \"ns\" |:value| \"0\" |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"ri\" |:name| \"ri\" |:value| \"afc4dac1-259a-4006-a979-8ab182d93cce\"
   |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"action_dialog_shown\" |:name| \"action_dialog_shown\" |:type| \"hidden\")
  (|:id| \"invid\" |:name| \"invid\" |:type| \"hidden\")
    (|:id| \"captcha_response\" |:name| \"captcha_response\" |:type| \"hidden\")) 
"
```

I have tried to use the function `read-from-string` to convert this list as a string to be a real list. This approach works with sample examples such as:

```
CL-USER> (read-from-string "((1 2 3) (a b c))")
((1 2 3) (A B C))
17
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use the same approach on the string previously mentioned I receive an error message:

```
CL-USER> (uiop:read-file-string "/home/pedro/miscellaneous/misc/tests-output/input-data.lisp")
CL-USER> (read-from-string *)
```

> too many colons in "36".
> Line: 1, Column: 26, File-Position: 26
> Stream: #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {10083FC0E3}>    [Condition
> of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR]

Why does this happen? And how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: nb: instead of doing both read-file-string and read-from-string, you can directly call "read" on an open stream: (with-open-file (in "/path/to/file.lisp") (read in))

Comment: If it's you who generated the date with `@2021…`, then you can print it with a simple `(format t "~a" local-time-date-objet)` and the `@` disappears, and your issue altogether I suppose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the date format.  `@2021-08-04T17:36:57.804411-03:00` is not a valid token in standard syntax.  You need to change to a readtable that includes the `@` reader macro from the library `local-time`.

Example interaction:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "local-time")
To load "local-time":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    local-time
; Loading "local-time"
[package local-time]......................
("local-time")
CL-USER> (local-time:enable-read-macros)
; No value
CL-USER> (read-from-string "@2021-08-04T17:36:57.804411-03:00")
@2021-08-04T22:36:57.804411+02:00
33
```